# Rearrange array of dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I would like to rearrange my array of dictionary from current dictionary to output

Current dictionary

```
[[1: ["hours": 4.0, "projectName": "starworks"]], [1: ["hours": 5.0, "projectName": "starworks"]], [2: ["hours": 7.0, "projectName": "Ada-solo"]] [2: ["hours": 5.0, "projectName": "Ada-solo"]]]
```

compare with array

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

output desire

```
[[1: ["hours": 4.0, "projectName": "starworks"], ["hours": 5.0, "projectName": "starworks"]], [2: ["hours": 7.0, "projectName": "Ada-solo"], ["hours": 5.0, "projectName": "Ada-solo"]]]
```

Comment: Convert dictionaries to objects first. Swift is not javascript, it does not work with dictionaries easily. Also, you actually have an array of dictionaries.

Comment: your output actually seems to be invalid, is it `[[Int: [[String: Any]]]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like what Sulthan says you can change the dictionary to a custom object, or you can loop through the dictionary with a foreach loop.

You could do something like this.

```
var dictArray = [[1: ["hours": 4.0, "projectName": "starworks"]], [1: ["hours": 5.0, "projectName": "starworks"]], [2: ["hours": 7.0, "projectName": "Ada-solo"]],[2: ["hours": 5.0, "projectName": "Ada-solo"]]]

var result = [Int: [[String:Any]]]()
dictArray.forEach { dict in

    // 1.  Make sure the key/values doe exist.
    guard let key = dict.first?.key, let value = dict.first?.value else { return }

    // 2. Check for existing data
    if var existingData = result[key] {

        // 3a. Append the new value
        existingData.append(value)
        result[key] = existingData
    } else {

        // 3b. Add the new value
        result[key] = [value]
    }
}
```